# Update datatype of parquet file without affecting existing data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, amazon-athena

I have a parquet file with multiple columns one of which is eg: col A with datatype timestamp. There are external Athena non partitioned  tables created on the S3 path. I want to change the datatype of the col A from timestamp to date , without having to rerun or affecting the existing data.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you won't add new files or the new files will also came with timestamps, just cast whenever you use it:

```sql
SELECT DATE(a) AS a, ... FROM table
```

If you will have new files with date column, it's more complicated. You cannot have mixed typed columns. It has to be either date or timestamp.

One workaround is creating a new column named like `a2` with date type, use this in the new files, and add it to the glue schema as well. Glue can handle missing columns, so a row from the old files will have `a` filled, but empty `a2`, and vice versa.

From now on you can use all files as:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(DATE(a), a2) AS a, ... FROM table
```

However I rather recommend to keep your files tidy, and use some ETL tool to convert the old parquet files to your current schema.